# DXT Texture working despite S3TC not being supported

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures

The topic involves OpenGL ES 2.0.

I have a device that when queried on the extensions via

```
glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)
```

Returns a list of supported extensions, none of which is `GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc` .

AFAIK , not haveing `GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc` shouldn't allow using DXT compressed textures.

However, when DXT compressed texture are used on the device , they render without any problems.

Texture data is commited using `glCompressedTexImage2D` .

Tried for DXT1 , DXT3 and DXT5 .

Why does it work ? Is it safe to use a texture compression although the compression seems to not be supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that missing support for `GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc` does not mean, that you can't use compressed formats. They may be supported anyway.

Quote from [glCompressedTexImage2D doc page for ES2](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCompressedTexImage2D.xml):

> The texture image is decoded according to the extension specification
>   defining the specified `internalformat`. OpenGL ES (...) provide a
>   mechanism to obtain symbolic constants for such formats provided by
>   extensions. **The number of compressed texture formats supported can be
>   obtained by querying the value of `GL_NUM_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS`.
>   The list of specific compressed texture formats supported can be
>   obtained by querying the value of `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS`.**

Note, that there is nothing about `GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc`. Support for various capabilities may be implemented even though their 'pseudo-standardized' (I mean - *extensionized*) substitutes are not listed as supported.

You should probably query those constants (`GL_NUM_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS` and `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS`) using [`glGetIntegerv()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) to learn, which compressed formats are *actually* supported.